# JQuery: Change all children-elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the values of the input elements (.child) of the next appending table-element by an blur event of .main

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="main" value="something">
<table>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td><input type="hidden" class="child" value="anything"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td><input type="hidden" class="child" value="anything"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text</td><td><input type="hidden" class="child" value="anything"></td></tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$( ".main" ).blur(function() {
    var content = $(this).val();
    $(this).next("table").find(".child").val(content));
});
```

Comment: make a JSFiddle and further explain what you mean. Its very unclear.

Comment: That's what you need: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".main" ).blur(function() {
    var content = $(this).val();
    $(this).next("table").find(".child").val(content); // Remove ')' here
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/k6qCx/

Comment: What is the difference between `find` and `each` in this context? Because of the comment from MelanicialUK above...

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$(".main").blur(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $(this).next("table").find("td .child").each(function() {
        $(this).val(val);
    });
});
```

Comment: his `.child` is an input element

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".main").blur(function() {
    var content = $(this).val();
    $(this).next("table").find(".child").val(content);
});
```

**Note:** You had an extra `)` after `(content)) <--- remove that`